# Why Does This Category Work? Category vs. Class Extension

Tags: objective-c, categories, class-extensions

This is what I have in my implementation file for one of my classes...

Code Setup #1

```
@interface MyViewController (PrivateMethods)
- (NSString *)myPrivateMethod;
@end

@implementation MyViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *myString = [self myPrivateMethod];
    NSLog(@"%@", myString);
}

- (NSString *)myPrivateMethod
{
    return @"someString";
}
@end
```

With this code, everything works and it logs "someString".

But shouldn't my code look differently somehow?  I actually am using that category by accident (I had copy/pasted something and didn't notice "PrivateMethods" was there; I meant to be using a class extension).

Shouldn't my code actually look like one of the following:

Code Setup #2

```
@interface MyViewController ()
- (NSString *)myPrivateMethod;
@end

@implementation MyViewController
....
```

Or:

Code Setup #3

```
@interface MyViewController (PrivateMethods)
- (NSString *)myPrivateMethod;
@end

@implementation MyViewController (PrivateMethods)
....
```

What are the nuances behind what is happening in this situation?  How is Code Setup #1 different from Code Setup #2?

Edit:  Question about Setup #3

What does setting it up like this accomplish?  Would this even "work"?

```
@interface MyViewController (PrivateMethods)
- (NSString *)myPrivateMethod;
@end

@implementation MyViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *myString = [self myPrivateMethod];
    NSLog(@"%@", myString);
}
@end

@implementation MyViewController (PrivateMethods)
- (NSString *)myPrivateMethod
{
    return @"someString";
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the selectors just get pushed into the same flat namespace at runtime. the compiler adds no additional code to distinguish that the selector is a method defined in a category (when messaging) --it's all flat.

the categories' symbols are exported differently, but that does not really matter to the runtime once loaded.

you should generally use Setup #3: if a method is declared in a category, it should be defined in the category's `@implementation`. the compiler will save you occasionally and it is a purer structure. (of course, not every method belongs in a category). Similarly, the declarations in the `@interface` should be defined in the corresponding `@implementation`, and definitions of declarations in the class continuation (`@interface MONClass ()`) should also appear in the primary `@implementation`:

```
@implementation MONClass
// add your @interface MONClass definitions here
// also add your @interface MONClass () definitions here
@end
```

**Updated Question**

Yes, that would work fine. All you should need to do is `#import` the header which contains `@interface MyViewController (PrivateMethods)`. I actually do this in some classes to categorize/organize by topic.

Typically, "Private Methods" are declared in the class continuation, but it is not necessary to do so (ivars/properties OTOH…).

Comment: Updating my question with another question about Setup #3.  Thanks so far though!

Comment: I believe it's also significant in this case that (recent) Clang will treat an otherwise-undeclared method's definition as being a declaration for the same `@implementation` .

Comment: I am "sort of" aware of that Josh.  Is that just with the new Xcode though or not?

Comment: @MikeS: I'm not sure which compiler version it started with. It's been around for a few Xcode v's, though. At least since 4.2.

Comment: @JoshCaswell yes, good point (+1). clang now supports parsing of the entire `@implementation` scope. previously, this was possible, but the restriction was that the definition needed to precede use of the selector. since every `@implementation` block must be closed, it is a nice addition.

Comment: to demonstrate, assuming neither selector is declared in an interface: `@implementation MONObject \n 
- (void)a { [self b]; /* << warning - b not declared */ } \n 
- (void)b { [self a]; /* OK - a is visible */ } \n 
@end` that *used to be* an issue, but clang is able to match the selector appropriately now.

Comment: Oh, right, it's just that ordering isn't significant anymore.